# Network Visualization for articles with shared keywords in R

Tags: r, networking, matrix, graph, diagram

I have a group of articles that I extracted the keywords from them. I ended up with a matrix, in R, with the articles as columns and keywords as rows and the value between each article+keyword is the number of occurrences of that keyword inside that article. I would like to visualize the results as a network diagram between the articles showing the connections between those articles according to the number of shared keywords.

Here is an example of the matrix I am referring to.

```
  keywords  article1 article2 article3
  key1        0        2         1
  key2        0        1         0
  key3        1        1         1
```

I also tried to create a distance matrix from this using R as follows.

```
  article.dist <- dist(mt,method = "binary")
  article.mt <- as.matrix(article.dist)
```

which yielded a distance matrix like below

```
  keywords key1 key2 key3
  key1      0    0.3  0.6
  key2      0.3  0    0.3
  key3      0.6  0.3  0
```

I would like to visualize this as a network of with the articles as the bubbles and the nodes as the keywords connecting between the articles.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can consider using d3.js to do the visualization, which has many great examples. If you have the data in R, you can use Shiny+d3.js to present an interactive visualization.

Comment: I can use D3 to do the visualization but I wanted first to make sure my data can be presented and it is in valid format. Is my data in valid format? or it needs more transformation in order to get the correct results?

Comment: You need to convert the matrix into nodes and edges. You can probably choose a cutoff to prune some edges. There are many graph visualization software. Once converted to appropriate format you can easily visualize as well. Maybe there are R packages for graph visualization?

Comment: Considering one of the matrices above, would you please provide me with a code snippet showing how to convert the matrix to nodes and edges?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure from your question exactly the type of diagram you want.  But if you were trying to get a network showing articles, keywords, and lines proportional to the number of times a keyword appears in an article, below is a simple solution with the [network](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/network/index.html) package (disclaimer, I'm a maintainer) .

Sample data structure for your example above

```
keywords<-structure(c(0,0,1,2,1,1,1,0,1), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames=list(c('key1','key2','key3'),c('article1','article2','article3')))
> keywords
     article1 article2 article3
key1        0        2        1
key2        0        1        0
key3        1        1        1
```

Convert the matrix to a bipartite-network object with an edge attribute named 'count'

```
> library(network)
> keynet<-as.network(keywords,matrix.type='bipartite',ignore.eval=FALSE,names.eval='count')
```

Do a very basic network plot

```
> plot(keynet,displaylabels=TRUE,edge.lwd='count')
```

[image: example of simple keword network plot]

for a list of parameters for customizing the plot, view `?plot.network` help page.